# Upload a file using vuejs and laravel without a form

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

I'm using vue.js 2.1 and Laravel 5.4 to upload a file from a component without a form.

**Problem:** On the server side, this statement `return $request->file('my_file');` returns null. Why?

This is how the vue component looks like:

```
<template>
    <input id="my_file" type="file" @change="fileChanged($event)">
    <button v-if="my_file" @click="update">Upload</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            my_file: null,
        }
    },

    methods: {
        fileChanged(e) {
            var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
            if (!files.length)
                return;
            this.createImage(files[0]);
        },

        createImage(file) {
            var image = new Image();
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var vm = this;

            reader.onload = (e) => {
                vm.my_file = e.target.result;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        },

        update() {
            axios.put('/api/update/', {
                my_file: this.my_file,
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

On the server side, I have the following method:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    return $request->file('my_file');

    // $request->file('my_file')->store();
}
```

What am I missing? So I can use the function `$request->file('my_file')->store();` provided by Laravel to upload the file.

**EDIT**
I've changed the http verb from `put` to `post` like so:

```
trySomeThing () {
    var data = new FormData();
    var file = this.$refs.fileInput.files[0];
    data.append('attachment_file', file);
    data.append('msg', 'hello');

    axios.post('/api/try', data)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)
        });
},
```

On the controller, I have:

```
public function try(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('my_file')) {
        $file = $request->file('my_file');
        //$file->getFilename();
        return var_dump($file);
    } else {
        return var_dump($_POST);
    }
}
```

The request header contains:
[image: request]

The returned response shows this:

[image: response]

Comment: use ```formData``` in vuejs

Comment: https://medium.com/@jagadeshanh/image-upload-and-validation-using-laravel-and-vuejs-e71e0f094fbb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add a Vue reference to your file input.

```
<input id="my_file" type="file" @change="fileChanged($event)" ref="fileInput">
```

Then update your `update` method:

```
update() {
    var data = new FormData()
    var file = this.$refs.fileInput.files[0]
    data.append('my_file', file)
    axios.put('/api/update/', data)     
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
}
```

In your laravel application:

```
if ($request->hasFile('my_file')) {
   $file = $request->file('my_file');
   dd($file);
}
```

For more info: [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#files)

Comment: How do I retrieve the data from the server side? I tried to `return $request->my_file;` but null is returned.  On chrome devTools, I see that the request sent contains : `------WebKitFormBoundary9lOFAy36UFyjOmoh
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachment_file"; filename="794a4be39f0b96b4d5787e3e31f8b622.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundary9lOFAy36UFyjOmoh`

Comment: I've added an else to your php test. It returns what is in the `else` block. Which means `$request->hasFile('my_file')` returned `false`.

Comment: please see my question edit. I even tried with post. php doesn't get it.

Comment: @Warrio check this https://medium.com/@jagadeshanh/image-upload-and-validation-using-laravel-and-vuejs-e71e0f094fbb

Comment: @ Jagadesha NH : I already did.. that's where I got inspired to write my initial question.. But I'll try again.

Comment: @Ikbel: I added a simple repository `git clone git@bitbucket.org:warrio4/pr1.git` where you can see the result by yourself that no file is found on the backend using FormData and FileLoader.

Comment: @Warrio can you try checking for `$request->hasFile('attachement_file')` ?

Comment: @Ikbel: yes, it works in the new project!! so I'll start over again on my main project. Thanks a lot for your support :D

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: @Ikbel:FormData doesn't work with the verb PUT :\ but with POST!!

Answer (score 0):

Your view should look something like this

```
<template>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img :src="image" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="file" v-on:change="onFileChange" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" @click="upload">Upload</button>
        </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
img{
    max-height: 36px;
}
</style>
<script>
    export default{
    data(){
        return {
            image: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onFileChange(e) {
            let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
            if (!files.length)
                return;
            this.createImage(files[0]);
        },
        createImage(file) {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            let vm = this;
            reader.onload = (e) => {
                vm.image = e.target.result;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        },
        upload(){
            axios.post('/api/upload',{image: this.image}).then(response => {

            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: yes, I guess if it worked for him, it must work also for me.. I'll make a new project and give it another try from scratch and see the difference with mine.

Comment: @Warrio I am not using any form here.

Comment: I created a new project with your suggested code. Unfortunately it returns null again.
Here is a link to the repository `git clone git@bitbucket.org:warrio4/pr1.git` Please have a look